# How to return the updated string(array) after substitution

Tags: c#

I have an array of string (rows), every element of which has the same format: Name; Date; Status

What I want to do is to replace the "Date" with the date of today, here's the function:

```
private string[] Update(string[] rows)
    {
        DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
        foreach (string row in rows)
        {
            string[] terms = row.Split(';');
            terms[1] = thisDay.ToString();
        }

        return rows;
    }
```

However the returned rows isn't the updated one but still the old one. Is it that after the foreach() I should rebuild the array or not? Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: you are not modifying the rows array inside this method, just interating it, so it makes sense to be the old one. Do you mean to return something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not modifying the `rows`, use a `for` loop instead and set each row to a new value:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
     string[] terms = row[i].Split(';');
     terms[1] = thisDay.ToString();
     row[i] = string.Join(";", terms);
}
```

Comment: So it's true that the element of rows need to be rebuilt. Thank you!